# How to setup trigger using temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to setup a trigger for database (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server).

I have 2 tables in it

```
create table atbv_Sales_Products 
(
     ProductID integer, 
     TotalQuantity integer
);

insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (1, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (2, 2);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (3, 20);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (4, 10);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (5, 20);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (6, 10);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (7, 5);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (8, 50);
insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (9, 1);

create table atbv_Sales_OrdersLines 
(
     OrderID integer, 
     ProductID integer, 
     Amount integer
);

insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (6, 4, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (6, 6, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (6, 1, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (47, 4, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (6, 9, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (5, 7, 1);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (6, 2, 2);
```

And there is an insert table (its actually autogenerated, but let's put it here for clarity sake

```
create table Inserted 
(
     OrderID integer, 
     ProductID integer, 
     Amount integer
);

insert into Inserted values (48, 4, 9);
insert into Inserted values (48, 1, 10);
insert into Inserted values (48, 8, 100);
insert into Inserted values (48, 2, 1);
```

For easier understanding here is how those tables look like graphically:

Products table

[image: Products table]

OrdersLines table

[image: OrdersLines table]

Insert table

[image: Insert table]

Now the trigger should check if inserted Amount values + Amount values from before go over TotalQuantity (which is a static value. Or in other words, it's not gonna change when new orders come in) and if so rollback the changes

For filtering that i use this portion of the code

```
IF EXISTS (select p.ProductID 
           from atbv_Sales_Products p 
           join Inserted i
           on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
           join atbv_Sales_OrdersLines ol
           on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
           group by i.ProductID, i.Amount, p.TotalQuantity
           having (SUM(ol.Amount) + i.Amount) > p.TotalQuantity)
```

And then I've been trying to use the following code portion of the code to rollback the changes and alert the error

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProductID NVARCHAR(60)
            SET @ProductID = (SELECT p.ProductID 
                                    FROM atbv_Sales_Products p
                                    JOIN inserted i 
                                    ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID)
            RAISERROR ('----There is not enough items number (%s) left----', 18, 1, @ProductName) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
            RETURN
END
```

Which works fine if there is one inserted row only, but I don't know what to do if there are multiple rows like in current example. I think I've read somewhere I could create a temporary table but again, don't know how to insert those values that are filtered out by first portion of the code into it and then use those values to display in in error message.

Comment: Do you just want a distinct list of product id's, separated by, say, commas?

Comment: @Xedni I want to display IDs of products going over TotalQuantity with new insert in an error message and rollback changes, because they cannot be applied  (second part is done by `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a temp table if you wanted, but I think that introduces an unnecessary step. What I would do is just serialize all the bad product ids into a variable, then check whether that variable is null (this would replace your `EXISTS` statement.

```
declare @BadProducts varchar(max)

select @BadProducts = 
    stuff((select ',' + p.ProductId
           from atbv_Sales_Products p 
           join Inserted i
           on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
           join atbv_Sales_OrdersLines ol
           on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
           group by i.ProductID, i.Amount, p.TotalQuantity
           having (SUM(ol.Amount) + i.Amount) > p.TotalQuantity
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

if @BadProducts is not null
begin
    raiserror('These products are bad: %s', 16, 1, @BadProducts)
    return
end
```

The alternative would be to insert the rows into a temp table or table variable (as you suggest), then do an existence check or a `@@rowcount` check against the temp table, and if either match, serialize the product ids in largely the same way as the first example (except replacing the whole big subquery with just your temp table). Something like this:

```
declare @badProductsTable table
(
    ProductId int
)

insert into @badProductsTable (ProductId)
select p.ProductId
from atbv_Sales_Products p 
join Inserted i
on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
join atbv_Sales_OrdersLines ol
on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
group by i.ProductID, i.Amount, p.TotalQuantity
having (SUM(ol.Amount) + i.Amount) > p.TotalQuantity

if @@rowcount > 0
    -- or you could do
    -- if exists (select 1 from @badProductsTable)
begin
    select @BadProducts = 
        stuff((select ',' + ProductId
               from @badProductsTable
               for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

    raiserror('These products are bad: %s', 16, 1, @BadProducts)
    return

end
```

Comment: Haven't thought of it this way (and didnt know stuff function too). Also tried the first method, and it works. Thanks, I've learned something

Comment: If you don't mind, why is there `','` in the select statement exactly? i dont seem to find any statements regarding that

Comment: Right. So when you use `FOR XML`, it concatenates every `ProductId`. Trouble is, if you don't put in a delimiter, you'll end up with product ids 1, 2 and 3 becoming the string `'123'` when what you really want is `'1,2,3'`. So you prepend the comma to every product id. Now other programming languages are nice enough to know you don't want a leading comma there, but SQL does not. So you can use the `STUFF()` function to replace the first character (i.e. the first comma) with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your If Exists statement is really what you need.  This script worked for me...

```
-- DROP table atbv_Sales_Products 
create table atbv_Sales_Products 
(
     ProductID integer, 
     TotalQuantity integer
);

insert into atbv_Sales_Products values (1, 10);

-- DROP table atbv_Sales_OrdersLines 
create table atbv_Sales_OrdersLines 
(
     OrderID integer, 
     ProductID integer, 
     Amount integer
);

insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (100, 1, 4);


CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON atbv_Sales_OrdersLines AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT      *
        FROM        (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Amount) as [Amount] FROM Inserted GROUP BY ProductID) I
        LEFT JOIN   (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Amount) as [Amount] FROM atbv_Sales_OrdersLines X WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted Y WHERE Y.OrderID = X.OrderID) GROUP BY ProductID) OL ON OL.ProductID = I.ProductID
        JOIN        atbv_Sales_Products P ON P.ProductID = I.ProductID
        WHERE       I.Amount + ISNULL(OL.Amount, 0) > P.TotalQuantity
    )
        THROW 51000, 'My Error Message.', 1;
GO

-------------

SELECT * FROM atbv_Sales_Products
SELECT * FROM atbv_Sales_OrdersLines

insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (101, 1, 4);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (102, 1, 2);
insert into atbv_Sales_OrdersLines values (103, 1, 1);
```

Also, consider finding a way to use a CHECK constraint as opposed to a trigger.  Triggers can often cause maintenance problems and performance problems, down the road.

Lastly, this example is academic, only.  As orders come in over multiple days and the available quantity fluctuates, this solution will not work very well.  It works to illustrate a point, but I hope that this is just for academic purposes.

Comment: If listing all of the product IDs that are overdrawn is a requirement, change the trigger slightly.  Change the "*" to ProductID and use STUFF and FOR XML PATH to concatenate the IDs.  [Here is a link that should be helpful](https://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stuff-and-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation/).

Comment: though it is for academic purposes, as DeadZone said, listing which products were overdrawn is a requirment, thus i went with Xedni suggestion (also what DeadZone was suggesting).